# How to properly return an image in the response in Spring app?

Tags: java, image, spring, httpresponse

I 'm using Spring 3.0.1.RELEASE for my webapp (and i have no way for upgrading it) and i'm trying to render some images from database on web-page.

I have following simple Spring configs:

spring-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me" />

    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="com.me.dbaccess.HibernateSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

spring-mvc.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="com.me.util.TilesExposingBeansViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="com.me.util.TilesExposingBeansView"/>
        <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/config/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have following controller:

```
@Controller
public class PhotoController {
    @RequestMapping("/carPhoto.html")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getCarPhoto(
            @RequestParam(UrlParameters.PHOTO_ID) Integer photoId,
            @RequestParam(UrlParameters.PHOTO_TYPE) String photoType) {
        //return image's bytes array from db by photo Id and Type;
    }
}
```

And finally, I have simple jsp-page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<img id="photoImage" src="<c:url value="/carPhoto.html?photoType=1&photoId=22556793"/>" />
```

If I open this page  - I can see this image without any problems.

But if I copy image "src" attribute and paste it in browser's address bar (Firefox 19.0.2) - then browser offers me to save carPhoto.html, instead of just render the image. 
Should I perform some additional setup?

Comment: is thie issue resolved, if yes please share how, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, that you have to specify the mime type (and if your image is larger you will need to specify its length too).

An other solution () is to return a [Spring `ResponseEntity`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) or [`HttpEntity`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) (HttpEntity is enough if you always return http status code 200, ResponseEntity (a subclass of HttpEntity) is for example needed if you want to return other http status codes, like not found).

```
@Controller
public class PhotoController {
    @RequestMapping("/carPhoto.html")
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> getCarPhoto(
            @RequestParam(UrlParameters.PHOTO_ID) Integer photoId,
            @RequestParam(UrlParameters.PHOTO_TYPE) String photoType) {


        byte[] image = image's bytes array from db by photo Id and Type;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG); //or what ever type it is
        headers.setContentLength(image.length);
        return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(image, headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'd love to use Your solution but i can't do it with my Spring version (3.0.1.RELEASE). HttpEntity and ResponseEntity are from 3.1.x, right?

Comment: `HttpEntity` and `ResponseEntity` are introduced in 3.0.2

Comment: I see, but anyway i can't use it, because i can't upgrade to 3.0.2. Are there any similar things in 3.0.1 ?

Comment: I dont know any. But I highly recommend to spend time on upgrading instead of copy features from new versions to old once (that a older than 3 years!)

Comment: Alas, this is not my decision to stay on this Spring version (or upgrade to newer version). I'm just using what i have and can't do anything with it :) Anyway, Thank You and CodeChimp for answers and for Your attention.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.  Easiest is to use @ResponseBody with a byte[] as your return type, set your Content-Type and such, the write the bytes to the output stream using the HttpServletResponse.

A more elegant solution (IMO) would be to return a ModelAndView, then set the View on that to a custom view that sets the proper headers (Content-Type and such) and writes out the bytes to the HttpServletResponse's output stream.

---

Comment: +1 for the analysis of the missing mime type, but you "more elegant solution" is a spring 2.x solution. Spring 3.x has some more elegant ways (IMO) (see my answer)

Comment: Upss. Can't edit my previous comment. 
Thank You for quick answer. I have tried to set up content-type but with no success (Maybe i'm doing it wrong):`  
    public byte[] getCarPhoto(  
            @RequestParam Integer photoId,  
            @RequestParam String photoType,  
            HttpServletResponse response) {  
        byte[] image = image from db; 
        response.setContentType("image/jpg");  
        response.setContentLength(image.length);  
        return image;  
    }  
`  As for 'more elegant solution' - is't it too much complicated for such a simple task? :)

Comment: You are missing the @ResponseBody on your return type.  You can either put it before the byte[] or the entire method.

Comment: @CodeChimp I have just omitted it in my comment, but actually i have it (as in my original code sample) before the entire method.

Comment: To set the content type, I think you can use Spring's built-in class MediaType like: response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG.toString());

Comment: @CodeChimp Thank You, but there is no such constant like MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG in my version of Spring. Seems like any solution people can provide here doesn't fits to my version of Spring :) And anyway, i think there is no difference how to setup content type, with my setContentType("image/jpg"), or with Yours setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG.toString()). Still it doesn't helps if i open an image in separate browser's tab.

Comment: If we knew what error/problem you saw, it may help.  For instance, are you getting the bytes to the browser, but it's not recognizing it as an image?  Or, is it simply not getting there at all?  Is there an HTTP error code?

Comment: @CodeChimp I thought i have described my problem pretty clear, well, looks like i didn't. Sorry for my english. I will try once more :) Yes, i'm getting bytes to the browser, but they are not recognized as an image. Browser offers me to save carPhoto.html page. If i save it, and then change file extension from "html" to "jpg" - it opens as an image. But i want browser to just show the image, not offering me to save it as web-page.

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Disposition header?  You need to set that to something like:  attachment; filename="my.jpg"